# Execute SQL query in sequence in protractor

Tags: promise, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e

I am using protractor tool for automation and using **mssql** to connect to DB, to execute any SQL query on database.

I have a bunch of queries which I need to execute but in sequence.

```
            sql1 = "delete from temp1"
            sql2 =  "delete from temp2"
            sql3 = "delete from temp3"
            .
            .
            sqln = "delete from tempn"

            **I have created below method to execute the queries- sqlcommands.js**
            var sql = require("mssql")

            var MSSqlExecution = function () {
             var dbConfig = {
                server: "00.00.00.00" ,
                database: "WQER" ,
                user: "REW" ,
                password: "WER",
                port: 11433,
                connectionTimeout: 999999999,
                requestTimeout: 999999999
             };

            this.executeQuery = function (sql_query){
                console.log("Executin query: "+sql_query);
                var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
                conn.connect().then(function(){
                    var req = new sql.Request(conn);
                    console.log("Executin query: "+sql_query);
                    req.query(sql_query).then(function(recordset){
                        console.log(recordset);
                        browser.sleep(12000);
                        conn.close();
                    }).catch(function(err){
                        console.log("Execute query error :  "+err);
                        conn.close();
                    });
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log("conn error :::: "+error);
                    conn.close();
                });
             };
            };
            module.exports = new MSSqlExecution();
```

Now I am calling these methods from my test class in beforeAll() method.

```
        var sqlQuery = require('../../../commands/sqlcommands.js');
         sqlQuery.executeQuery(SQl_query1);
            sqlQuery.executeQuery(SQl_query2);
            sqlQuery.executeQuery(SQl_query3);
            sqlQuery.executeQuery(SQl_queryn);
```

Now, I want to make sure that my code should wait until previous query is not yet completed and than only move to next query for execution. Currently all queries are getting executed without waiting for previous query to complete.

How can we make sure that next query is executed only when first query execution is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to send multiple commands as a single string?

SQL Server will see it as a single Transaction and ensure all commands are executed in Order.

```
sql1 = "delete from temp1;delete from temp2;delete from temp3;delete from temp3;...delete from tempN;"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Yes it will work but actually I wanted to wait for all the Queries to get executed before it moved to next step to perform some step on UI. Currently with your approach, queries are executed in sequence but before all queries are executed successfully, my scripts next steps starts getting executed on UI, which I dont want. Seems it need to be handled from protractor code.

Comment: @user1931543 you can execute the sql queries inside `protractor.promise.controlFlow().execute(sqlQuery.executeQuery(SQl_query1))`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the concept of **promise** which can only make the things sequential in protractor.

Function by whihh you can execute query in **javascript** while using **protractor** and otherwise too

1) Here how you can run a query by calling the custom function **runQuery**. We will be using nested with keyword **then**

Then helps by stopping until the first query runs. It will wait for age to come before calculating DOB

```
 query = " select age from employee"
 // Query to get age from employee
    db.runQuery(query).then(function (queryResult) {
        age = queryResult[0].age

        // here next query is dependent on first
        query = "select dob from employee where age = '" + age + "'";

        db.runQuery(query).then(function (queryResult) {
            dateofBirth = queryResult[0].dob;
         });
    })
 });
```

where runQuery is a function which is generic like executeQuery which is in another page

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var basePage = require('../pages/base_page.js');

var dbutil = function () {

this.runQuery = function (query) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var conn = basePage.buildAppsDbConnection();
        var req = new sql.Request(conn);
        conn.connect(function (err) {


            if (err) {

                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log("query = " + query);
            req.query(query + " for json auto;", function (err, recordset) {

                if (err) {

                    console.log(err);
                } else {



                        var desiredString = recordset['recordset'][0]['JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B'];
                        if (desiredString.length) {
                            var desiredJson = JSON.parse(desiredString);
                            console.log(desiredJson);
                            resolve(desiredJson);
                        }
                        else {
                             desiredJson = '{"For Query":"No Rows Returned"}';
                             resolve(desiredJson);
                        }

                }
                conn.close();
            })
        });


    });

}
 }

module.exports = new dbutil();
```

Here is the function in another page where we are storing the config

```
 var BasePage = function () {
  var sql = require('mssql');
  this.buildAppsDbConnection = function () {

var dbConfig = {

  server: "servernamehere",
  database: "DBname",
  user: "username",
  password: "password",
  options: {
    encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
  }

}
```